# Flutter ListView.Builder Not Updating on Subsequent Searches

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, search

I have a ListView.Builder that builds a list after a I perform a couple searches on the data.  It works great for the first search but when I go back to perform a subsequent search, it appear the data is cached somewhere and doesn't up the search.  I have the SetState updated but my understanding is that will not update the list.  My search criteria data fields are being updated correctly.  How do I get the list to update with each search?

Thanks in advance!

I'll try to add the code in snippets because no matter what I do, I get formatting error's and it won't let me post.
'''
Flutter

```
       Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: catIngs.length,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                 key: ObjectKey(catIngs[index]), //ADDED THIS KEY TO RESOLVE MY ISSUE.
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
                  // catIngs;
                  final _ings = catIngs[index];
                  final prodNameEnd = _ings.prodName;
                  final imglnk = _ings.imgLink;
                  return Material(
                    child: Container(
                      height: 90,
                      child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment:
```

Comment: Please share related code, so we will have better understanding of your problem.

Comment: You create new list by filtering with user input and list the same in UI.

Comment: I am forever in amazement of anyone who can actually get their code into StackOverflow.

Comment: @AlexSunderSingh how do you create a New List?  I am using Listbuilder and the new user data is in all of my data points but it's showing the cached data from the first search.  Thanks!

Comment: Can you add you code a text, so that we can help you

Comment: @AlexSunderSingh I have added the code. It's alot of code because I don't know what is causing the problem.

Comment: Still unable to identify issue, if you don't mind, can you share the code in github.

Comment: Do you at some point call `setState(() {catIngs = ...;});` ?

Comment: This problem was a challenge to resolve.  I have two searches on my data then I setState as you @Tijee  mention then build the list.  Before my next search begins (to build a new list from search), I clear all of the variables I was using in the previous search.  This gives me a fresh search data.  This may not be the best way to do it but I wasn't able to fully solve the issue any other way.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was a challenge to resolve. I have two searches on my data then I setState as you @Tijee mention then build the list. Before my next search begins (to build a new list from search), I clear all of the variables I was using in the previous search. This gives me a fresh search data. This may not be the best way to do it but I wasn't able to fully solve the issue any other way.